# Finding a key value by referencing another key value in the same dict level in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm having a hard time even coming up with the proper jargon to describe my issue. 
Basic idea is I have a dict that has the following structure:

```
myDict = 
"SomeMetric":{
    "day":[
        {"date": "2013-01-01","value": 1234},
        {"date": "2013-01-02","value": 5678},
        etc...
```

I want to pull out the "value" where the date is known. So I want:

```
myDict["SomeMetric"]["day"]["value"] where myDict["SomeMetric"]["day"]["date"] = "2013-01-02"
```

Is there a nice one-line method for this without iterating through the whole dict as my dict is much larger, and I'm already iterating through it, so I'd rather not do nested iteritems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator expressions to the resque:

```
next(d['value']
    for d in myDict['SomeMetric']['day']
    if d['date'] == "2013-01-02")
```

So, loop over all `day` dictionaries, and find the first one that matches the `date` you are looking for. This loop stops as soon as a match is found.

Comment: had the exact same answer, down to the choice of variable name. beaten by several secs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over your data structure? It seems to be constructed in such a way that lends itself to sub-optimal lookups.

I'd structure it as such:

`data = { 'metrics': { '2013-01-02': 1234, '2013-01-01': 4321 } }`

And then your lookup is simply:

`data['metrics']['2013-01-02']`

Comment: This is part of that process actually. I'm reorganizing the data. Part of that process involves aggregating some values. I'm beginning to think I should reorg first with no combining, then do my combining as a second step.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the structure?  If you can, you might  find it much easier to change the `day` list to a dictionary which has dates as keys and values as values, so

```
myDict = {
"SomeMetric":{
    "day":{
        "2013-01-01": 1234,
        "2013-01-02": 5678,
        etc...
```

Then you can just index into it directly with

```
myDict["SomeMetric"]["day"]["2013-01-02"]
```